# Redirect the output of the exe batch file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, batch-file

I want to execute a certain batch file and redirect its console output to a text control in visual c++ or redirect the console output at the same time the logs/echo are showing.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you have to make the run process to write to a pipe, and to read the output of this pipe.

[EDIT] I know how SciTE does that (you can take a look at the source: win32/SciTEWin.cxx, ExecuteOne function), I searched a slightly more generic way, found [How to spawn console processes with redirected standard handles](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B190351&x=15&y=14) from Microsoft itself.
If you seach *CreatePipe PeekNamedPipe CreateProcess* keyword, for example, you might find other examples.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [Boost.Process](http://highscore.de/boost/process/) *(Boost.Process is not (yet) an official Boost C++ library. It must be downloaded and installed separately)*.

The example "[Child.4 - Reading from a child using asynchronous I/O](http://highscore.de/boost/process/process/tutorials.html#process.tutorials.read_from_child)" shows how to redirect the output of the child process into a C++ stream (and later access the content).

Example "[Child.4 - Reading from a child using asynchronous I/O](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/process/tutorials.html#process.tutorials.async_io)" show how to use Boost.Process togehter with [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) to access the childs I/O *asynchronous*.

The advantages of this method is, that Boost.Process supports the Windows API and POSIX API.

Answer (score 0):

If elegance is not a priority then a really simple solution might be to redirect the output to a file, and then read in the file contents.